# Unable to run specflow tests using vstest.console.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, specflow, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to run `speflow` tests based on visual studio runner but getting error in `vsts`. I am using the following `vsts` test runner task:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe myassembly.dll
```

Error:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types
>
> Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I have tried:

```
/TestAdapterPath: "Adapterpath"/UseVsixExtensions:True/False(Both option)/Platform:[ platform type ]
```

... but none of these are working; tests are working fine in Visual Studio 2017, but are still not working in the CI job.

Comment: Which test runner are you using in combination with VSTest? SpecFlow+Runner, MsTest, XUnit, NUnit?

Comment: @AndreasWillich it's xunit

Comment: Is it a core test project? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the detail log on the OneDrive.

Comment: Yes it is core test project.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: Try to refer to these steps and check the result: 1. Refer to [SpecFlow+ Getting Started](http://specflow.org/getting-started/) article to create new specflow project. 2. Create a build definition with .Net Destop build template. Tasks: Nuget Tool Installer (Version of Nuget.exe to install: 4.3.0) 3. NuGet restore 4. Visual Studio Build 5. Visual Studio Test

Comment: I am trying to run the tests using MSTest runner and they used to work fine with visual studio 2015 once we upgraded build definition to target  newer version of .Net core, started facing issues. if I try calling vstest.console.exe from 2015 then it's unable to discover any test(I assume that's because build is targeting VS 2017) and vstest.console.exe from 2017 it's unable to run the tests cases successfully.

Comment: Can you share a simple sample project and build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I will try to replicate the issue with smaller project but I will require some work I am verifying API functionality end to end via specflow tests but any idea on how to enable ReflectionTypeLoadException.LoaderExceptions property, exception is being thrown by code behind file of feature file

Comment: Do you mean the error is in the code?

Comment: Yes It seems error is in the code and or in the package which is getting generated by vsts build, it could not some of the dependencies but i am not sure which one..

Comment: I have managed to figure out the issue. Actually VSTS build is causing this issue. I am referencing the NewtonSoft.Json.dll version 6.0.3.0 but also have runtime binding redirect to version 10.0.0.0 but some how nuget is restoring older version and when tests are running they are unable to find 10.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below lines of code helped me in identifying the missing dll now it's build which need to be fixed.

```
try
    {
    }
    catch (System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (System.Exception exSub in ex.LoaderExceptions)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(exSub.Message);
            System.IO.FileNotFoundException exFileNotFound = exSub as System.IO.FileNotFoundException;
            if (exFileNotFound != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exFileNotFound.FusionLog))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("Fusion Log:");
                    sb.AppendLine(exFileNotFound.FusionLog);
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        string errorMessage = sb.ToString();
        throw new System.Exception(errorMessage);
    }
```